# Can't see the image or movie file dimensions in Finder

Tags: macos, finder, graphics

I can't see the image or movie file dimensions in the Finder when browsing files on a server. Local files are shown as usual; it's just when I pick a file on the company server that the dimensions are not shown.

The screen shot below shows the dimensions of a local file, correctly, as 1280 x 720. Why is this information missing from server hosted files?

[image: Example with dimensions]

Comment: Please revive your question, this is very vague. And what are you relating to with "I have the same issue"? Could you please write it down as a question instead of a brainwave?

Comment: I would expect it is because the files are not indexed by spotlight

Answer (score 1):

Files on the remote server are not indexed by Spotlight. Try using identify or ffprobe:

```
brew install imagemagick ffmpeg
identify image.png
ffprobe -i video.mp4
```